# How dir() works

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how `dir()` works, I'm reading the doc but I still have some doubts.

From the doc:

> The default `dir()` mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information:
>
> - If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the
>     module's attributes.
> - If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its
>     bases.
> - Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes' names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of
>     its class’s base classes.

Because I'm not understaing the difference between the second and the third, I'm doing some experimentations on the interactive prompt:

```
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>> dir([])
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

I'm not understanding, I'm giving a type object (`dir(list)`) and I get the same list if I give a list object (`dir([])`), so what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `list` instance, such as the empty list object created by the literal `[]`, has the same attributes as the `list` class, so you get the same list back from `dir()`. However, as you can dynamically add attributes to (some) object instances in Python, that will not always be the case, hence the distinction made in the documentation. Here's an example where the instance has attributes the class doesn't:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def method(self):
        pass


>>> t = Test()
>>> t.foo = "bar" # additional attribute
>>> set(dir(t)).difference(dir(Test))
set(['foo']) # appears in dir
```

Comment: mmm...maybe I'm getting confused because on the Lutz's book it says I can use indifferently `dir([])` or `dir(list)`. However, I'm not getting the difference between the last 2 points yet. `list` is an type object, in particular an instance of `type`, so I can add to it some attributes dynamically, so I don't still see any difference..

Comment: No, actually, you can't add attributes to a `list` instance; that would cause an `AttributeError`. It is for this reason that `dir(list)` and `dir(a_list)` are the same; this is not *generally* true.

Comment: Can I add dynamically attributes to `type` instances (i.e. `dict`, `list`, customized class, and so on)?

Comment: You can dynamically add class attributes to custom classes (e.g. `Test.foo = "bar"`), but you can't to the built-in types (e. g. no `list.foo = 'bar'`).

Comment: ok, I think I understood, but the doc is a bit confusing, because if I see `Test` (your class) as a `type` instance then the second item from the doc can be deleted. don't you agree?

Comment: No - it could perhaps be clearer, but it's: 1. module; 2. class (or type); 3. instance (including e.g. function class instances).

Comment: Oh you are right, the 2 item in the list is important because if it was deleted then all the attributes present in the list `dir(type)` should show up if I call `dir(list)`

Answer (score 0):

The second item specifically refers to types or classes; that leaves the third item to cover *instances* of types or classes.

Note the last line of the output from `dir` for the class `A` compared to the last line for `a`, an instance of `A`. `a` has an attribute `y` which `A` does not. (I broke the output onto multiple lines for readability here.)

```
>>> class A(object):
...   x = 3
...   def __init__(self, b):
...     self.y = b
...
>>> a = A(6)
>>> dir(A)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__',
 'x']
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__',
 'x', 'y']
>>>
```